# one line shell command to find a pattern filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh

In closed application, I have to catch a string in a variable ($text) like:

```
A00_ABC_OK
```

, and I have to filter a single file like:

```
XA00_ABC
```

Where X can be any character.

On this closed application I just can put a one line shell command, and scripts don't work. I tried this differents commands, but no one work rigth

```
echo $text | sed 's/_OK//;s/^/*/' | xargs ls
```

A00_ABC_OK -> *A00_ABC -> ls *A00_ABC = dont work

```
echo $text | sed 's/_OK//;s/^/*/' | xargs find -name
```

A00_ABC_OK -> *A00_ABC -> find -name *A00_ABC = dont work

```
ls -1 | grep < echo $text | sed 's/_OK//;'
```

ls -1 -> grep A00_ABC

I'm using a Server with Linux CentOS

Thanks!

Comment: All of these incantations assume that the file is in or under the same directory that the "closed application" resides in; is that assumption correct? If no, I'd try with a modified version of your 2nd example; **echo $text | sed 's/_OK//;s/^./*/' | xargs -i find /path/to/dir -name "{}" \;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards are expanded by the shell, but `xargs` doesn't use the shell to execute the command after it adds the arguments from its standard input.

Instead of putting the wildcard into the variable, you can just put it into your command. You can use the shell's built-in parameter expansion substitution operator to remove the `_OK` from the value.

```
ls *"${text/_OK/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

another way in which you can you do it

```
$ ls *A00_ABC
gA00_ABC  xA00_ABC
$ text="A00_ABC_OK"
$ ls $(echo $text | sed 's/_OK//;s/^/*/')
gA00_ABC  xA00_ABC
$
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo $text | sed 's/_OK//;s/^/*/' | xargs -I % find . -name %` also works